# Arduino and TinyGPS++ convert lat and long to a string

Tags: string, arduino

I' m having a problem parsing the lat and long cords from TinyGPS++ to a Double or a string. The code that i'm using is:

```
String latt = ((gps.location.lat(),6));
String lngg = ((gps.location.lng(),6));

Serial.println(latt);
Serial.println(lngg);
```

The output that i'm getting is:

> 0.06

Does somebody know what i'm doing wrong? Does it have something to do with rounding? (Math.Round) function in Arduino.

Thanks!

Comment: Is that for latt or lngg?

Comment: Both. lat and long are outputting 0.006.

Comment: Serial.println((gps.location.lat(),6));
Does just work fine.

Comment: What is the full value of gps.location.lat()?

Comment: 0.06 that's what i'm getting in my serial.

Comment: No, that's the value of latt?

Comment: Latt and longg are both outputting 0.06. When i'm directly printing gps.location.lng(),6 it is outputting a normal cord.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems:

#### 1. This does not compile:

```
String latt = ((gps.location.lat(),6));
```

The error I get is

```
Wouter.ino:4: warning: left-hand operand of comma has no effect
Wouter:4: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*'
Wouter:4: error: initializing argument 1 of 'String::String(const char*)'
```

There is nothing in the definition of the String class that would allow this statement.  I was unable to reproduce printing values of `0.06` (in your question) or `0.006` (in a later comment).  Please edit your post to have the exact code that compiles, runs and prints those values.

#### 2. You are unintentionally using the comma operator.

There are two places a comma can be used: to separate arguments to a function call, and to separate multiple expressions which evaluate to the last expression.

You're not calling a function here, so it is the latter use.  What does that mean?  Here's an example:

```
int x = (1+y, 2*y, 3+(int)sin(y), 4);
```

The variable `x` will be assigned the value of the *last* expression, `4`.  There are very few reasons that anyone would actually use the comma operator in this way.  It is much more understandable to write:

```
int x;
1+y;              // Just a calculation, result never used
2*y;              // Just a calculation, result never used
3 + (int) sin(y); // Just a calculation, result never used
x = 4;            // A (trivial) calculation, result stored in 'x'
```

The compiler will usually optimize out the first 3 statements and only generate code for the last one<sup>1</sup>.  I usually see the comma operator in `#define` macros that are trying to avoid multiple statements.

For your code, the compiler sees this

```
((gps.location.lat(),6))
```

And evaluates it as a call to `gps.location.lat()`, which returns a `double` value.  The compiler throws this value away, and even warns you that it "has no effect."

Next, it sees a `6`, which is the actual value of this expression.  The parentheses get popped, leaving the `6` value to be assigned to the left-hand side of the statement, `String latt =`.

If you look at the declaration of `String`, it does not define how to take an int like `6` and either construct a new `String`, or assign it `6`.  The compiler sees that `String` *can* be constructed from `const char *`, so it tells you that it can't convert a numeric `6` to a `const char *`.

### Unlike a compiler, I think I can understand what you intended:

```
double latt = gps.location.lat();
double lngg = gps.location.lon();
Serial.println( latt, 6 );
Serial.println( lngg, 6 );
```

The `6` is intended as an argument to `Serial.println`.  And those arguments are correctly separated by a comma.

As a further bonus, it does not use the `String` class, which will undoubtedly cause headaches later.  Really, don't use `String`.  Instead, hold on to numeric values, like `int`s and `float`s, and convert them to text at the last possible moment (e.g, with `println`).

I have often wished for a compiler that would do what I mean, not what I say.  :D

---

<sup>1</sup>   Depending on `y`'s *type*, evaluating the expression `2*y` may have side effects that cannot be optimized away.  The streaming operator `<<` is a good example of a mathematical operator (left shift) with side effects that cannot be optimized away.

And in your code, calling `gps.location.lat()` may have modified something internal to the `gps` or `location` classes, so the compiler may not have optimized the function call away.

In all cases, the *result* of the call is not assigned because only the last expression value (the 6) is used for assignment.

Comment: Thanks for explaining to me! That is some clear information. Can you might specify how i can work around this problem? Thank you so much!

Comment: The last code section in mym answer is what you do.  I added the longitude.

Comment: Your explanation of the comma operator is incorrect. The intermediate values do *not* get assigned - only the right-most one. This is always the case regardless of compiler or optimization.

Comment: Hmm... "to separate multiple expressions which evaluate to the last expression" seems pretty clear and correct, and I would have thought "theoretical" would be understood to mean "not actual".  As an answer to a newbie question, I try to avoid getting legal, preferring to introduce just a few new terms of the jargon.  The new footnote broaches a few of the related *expert* topics.